# Can't publish my linux Flutter app on snapcraft

Tags: linux, flutter, publishing, snapcraft

I created a Linux app using flutter & when i tried to publish the app on the snapcraft following the steps on :

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/linux

I get error : Failed to load extension 'flutter-master': this extension does not support the 'core20' base .

I tried to change to change the flutter branch to dev and change the core base to (18 - 22)
the problem always the same this extension not support this core .

Answer (score 2):

core 18 is the one with the plugin for flutter core 20 does not have the plugin nor the most recent core 22 I leave you the documentation of it
https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-plugins